# How do I combine anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, plugins

*From looking on SO and elsewhere it doesn't look like there is a way to extend anonymous functions.* 
...However, see I Google doing something similar in their google analytics (analytics.js) tracking script and I'm not sure how to replicate the same.

Basically I have a bunch of methods wrapped in an anonymous function. I don't want them leaking into the global namespace.

However... I need to be able to let the user optionally load plugins (that are in separate javascript files) that 'extend' the original script. I do this to keep the original script as small as possible. I can't see a way to break up my script into multiple files and then join then together on the fly based on options the user specifies without exposing all of the methods so that they can communicate. This however will also make them available to other people and hence they may not be using the script as intended.

**So in summary, I want to have:**

```
(function() {
// Main.js
....
Based on user input combine with plugin1.js so i can call his methods and he can call mine
})();

(function() {
// Plugin1.js
// More methods
})();
```

Is there any ways or workaround to accomplish this without exposing all my methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of [revealing module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript) and a single global namespace object. Like this:

```
//main.js
if (window.MY_APP === undefined) {
    window.MY_APP = {};
}

window.MY_APP.main = (function () {
    //Your code
    var registerPlugin = function() { ... },
        unregisterPlugin = function () { ... };


    return { //Here you expose the functions you want to be public
        registerPlugin: registerPlugin,
        unregisterPlug: unregisterPlugin
    };
}());

//Plugin.js
if (window.MY_APP === undefined) {
    window.MY_APP = {};
}

window.MY_APP.myPlugin = (function() {
    //Plugin code


    return {
       //public methods of plugin 
    };
}());
```

Comment: This is nice code, although I think it leaves me with the same issue. I still have to expose methods to the plugin from the main code that other users will then have access to. So if I have a bunch of utility functions the plugin needs access to, now they are also public.

Comment: Okay, write your plugins to take an argument which is an object with the utility functions. Then when the main code initializes the plugin pass that object to the plugin. This way only the plugin will have access to the utility functions

Comment: Brilliant. I think that's probably what i need.

Comment: So are you saying to use a constructor on the plugin and use var plugin = new Plugin(UtilObj)?

Comment: I guess in this case my plugin couldn't be an anonymous function anymore?

Comment: Yes exactly like that and you plugin can still be in an anonymous function, you just have to expose the constructor function using the revealing module pattern as shown above.

Comment: Sorry to be dense but I'm thinking it would be impossible to use a self executing function.. I'm thinking I would have to do something like var Plugin = function() { }  which is not a big deal although I want to make sure i understand what you are saying. Also I wouldn't be able to assign the plugin as you show because I'd have to pass it the util object. So i'd have to assign it from the main. Can you show me how you would pass the util doing it like this: window.MY_APP.myPlugin = (function() { .... when the util is not public. I'm thinking i'd have to do this.Survey = __pluginName(myUtil)

Comment: Also doing this would make my plugin methods public to everyone else. Anything I need to expose to my main module will then become public basically right? One idea might be for me to expose an attach method to my main class that the plugin can pass itself to. The attach method can then receive the plugin and assign it to a private variable. Maybe this is overkill :).

Answer (score 1):

## Probable Solution

Here is a fun solution I just figured out. It is pretty much self explanatory and I commented the code. Hope it serves the purpose.

```
var p1 = (function (self) {
    // private stuff - 
    var hiddenInfo1 = "PlugIn 1's Secret Info";
    var hiddenMethod1 = function () {
        alert(hiddenInfo1);
    }
    // public stuff
    self.exposedMethod = function () {
        alert("PlugIn 1's Public Info");
    }
    self.getPrivateAccess = function () {
        return {
            seal: function () { delete self.getPrivateAccess },
            // - list of shared private stuffs
            hiddenMethod1: hiddenMethod1,
        }
    }
    return self;
})(p1 || {});
```

Later you create a Master/Combo

```
var master = (function (self, p1) {
    // get p1's private stuffs.
    var p1sPrivs = p1.getPrivateAccess();
    // now seal p1 so that no one else can request it.
    p1sPrivs.seal();
    // just to make sure, uncomment this line and get a runtime error. ;)
    // p1.getPrivateAccess();

    // let's define a function for the masses....
    self.shoutAll = function () {
        p1.exposedMethod();
        p1sPrivs.hiddenMethod1();
        alert("Master's Public Method");
    }
    return self;
})(master || {}, p1);

// now use it.
master.shoutAll();
```

---

The idea comes from this awesome article located at http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html. Especially into the section called `Cross-File Private State`.

> One severe limitation of splitting a module across multiple files is
>   that each file maintains its own private state, and does not get
>   access to the private state of the other files. This can be fixed.
>   Here is an example of a loosely augmented module that will maintain
>   private state across all augmentations:

```
var MODULE = (function (my) {
    var _private = my._private = my._private || {},
        _seal = my._seal = my._seal || function () {
            delete my._private;
            delete my._seal;
            delete my._unseal;
        },
        _unseal = my._unseal = my._unseal || function () {
            my._private = _private;
            my._seal = _seal;
            my._unseal = _unseal;
        };

    // permanent access to _private, _seal, and _unseal

    return my;
}(MODULE || {}));
```

> Any file can set properties on their local variable _private, and it
>   will be immediately available to the others. Once this module has
>   loaded completely, the application should call MODULE._seal(), which
>   will prevent external access to the internal _private. If this module
>   were to be augmented again, further in the application’s lifetime, one
>   of the internal methods, in any file, can call _unseal() before
>   loading the new file, and call _seal() again after it has been
>   executed.

Comment: I think this may be exactly what I need, but how do I pass the main module to the plugin? I can't pass 'this' or it will pass the window object. I don't have a variable that I use for my main anonymous function because i'm not using exposing any methods.

Comment: Just updated the answer with something more appropriate for the case in hand. Let me know if it helps.